# using bash scripting for extracting data to various files

Tags: bash, awk

using bash scripting for extracting data to various files

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=10; i++){if($1== 2**($i)){getline; print}}}' test.csv>> test/test_$i.csv
```

Description; I want to extract data to multiple files where column 1 of input file has sizes in power of 2. I want to extract rows having same size into a different file.
input file:

```
4                      10.06              9.64             10.36        1000
8                      10.16              9.79             10.48        1000
16                     10.49             10.02             10.86        1000
32                     10.54             10.13             10.91        1000
4                      10.76              9.64             10.36        1000
8                      10.90              9.79             10.48        1000
```

Comment: [edit] your question to format your code, input, and output to be readable by using the editor's `{}` button, Also clarify what your question is - what you've posted so far is just a statement, there's no question in there.

Comment: it's unclear, what do expect as a result ?

Comment: Do you want somethig more complicated than `awk '{print > "test"$1".out"}' test.csv`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this before you post any more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'log($1)/log(2) == int(log($1)/log(2)) { out="pow-" $1; print >out }' file.in
```

This will, for the given data, create the files `pow-N` for N equal to 4, 8, 16 and 32.

It will skip lines that does not have a number that is a power of 2 in its first column.

Comment: @EdMorton The difference is that with `>`, the output file would be truncated with each run of the script. But you're right, in this case we might as well use just `>`,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I figured out the possible solution:

```
for i in `seq 0 $numline`
do
   if [ -e $InDir/$file ]
   then
      awk -v itr=$i '{if($2== 2**(itr)) {print $0}}' $file >> $OutDir/$(awk "BEGIN{print (2 ** $i)}")mb_$file
   fi
done
```